# Cannot add message to storage queue using c#

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I have an azure `QueueTrigger` function which processes messages when I add them using the `Azure Storage Explorer` tool.

I now need to add messages to the queue programatically in C#. I've created a .Net Core console application, installed the `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet package.

In Azure I have gone to my functions storage account and from the Access Keys section, copied the connection string, [for the below code:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#insert-a-message-into-a-queue)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("RedactedConnectionString");

    // Create the queue client.
    CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

    // Retrieve a reference to a queue.
    CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("test-messages");

    // Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
    //queue.CreateIfNotExists();

    // Create a message and add it to the queue.
    CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello, World");

    var result = queue.AddMessageAsync(message);

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Once this code runs, no message is queued, and if I inspect the `result` variable, all i see is this:

[image]

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Not that it's necessarily the cause of your issue but... you're calling the `Async()` method to add your message, without an `await`...

Comment: I cant because its a console application

Comment: @JsonStatham you can use `async Main` in C# 7.3 [ref](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/12/08/async-main-is-available-but-hidden/). Or do `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on all async calls

Comment: @trailmax You should put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @trailmax This worked, please turn your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using `await` and the request to create a message is never executed.

You can either use latest C# (7.3 currently) to use `async Main` and have it looking like this:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
...
    await queue.AddMessageAsync(message);
...
}
```

Or you can use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on your async call:

```
queue.AddMessageAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```